# Remote Web desktop requires Admin rights for initial launch

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-7, remote-desktop-services

A client of ours has begun a rollout of a system that requires the use of Remote Desktop Web Access for their NOC.

Each site is configured for RDWA and has a unique URI. When accessing the web interface end users are presented with a login screen as expected [Figure 1]. They open, the Active X RDWA component appears to launch [figure 2] and they are asked to login to the remote computer [Figure 3] but then receive an error [Figure 4]

[image: First Screen]

*Figure 1*
[image: Active X RDWA Control Launches]

*Figure 2*
[image: Remote Login]

*Figure 3*
[image: Error Message]

*Figure 4*

This issue goes away if a single connection is attempted whith the browser running as administrator. If the browser launches as administrator Figure 1 - 3 are the same, they you see a blue logon screen and everything works. Subsequent connections with the browser running *without* administrative credentials are fine.

However this only works per site and per user. We'll have 700 sites in the next five years, and the operaitons centre who need access have 40 users who don't sit in the same seat every day. Of course allowing end users admin access isn't acceptable.

I've not encountered this before.

Other salient points.

1. The remote system is an 'off the shelf' deployment from a third party, and not  a configuration I can control. Their response was that 'it works for them' and the issue was local to the desktop running RDWA (as demonstrated by using local admin creds).
2. The remote system is in a seperate domain with no trust relationship existing between the two.
3. Remote system is 2008 R2

   My initial thoughts were that the Active X control for RDWA wasn't being allowed to launch. To resolve that I created a new GPO that put these sites within the Intranet zone and then set all controls on that zone to 'Allow/accept', this had no effect (RSOP shows the successful application of the GPO).

It appears that Active X *is* launching, as we can see in figure 2 above. However there now seems to be a subsequent piece of VB script that is attempting to execute locally, but I can't locate what it is or what it may do.

Anyone able to offer any thoughts on what steps I can take to locate the cause of this issue?

EDIT :
In response to Drifter104.

I had come across the registry key mentioned and had tested it. It had no effect. It seems that this fixes the same issue for full fat RDP client but didn't effect the RDWA client.

Re-running as admin did not re-create the MS Licensing key on the test machine.

We have a work around for now (HKCU\Software\Internet Explorer\main\TabProcGrowth set to 0). Although performance is poor.

Answer (score 0):

VB has nothing to do with the cause of the error.

This is a common error all the way back to xp and is normally caused because the licensing mode of the server you are connecting to is set to per device. To resolve the issue delete the following registry key

```
 HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSLicensing
```

However if after deleting this you still have the issue, then you need to connect once again with Run As Administrator. I know you don't want to do this, and I completely agree with why. However this is the accepted fix for the problem.

It would also be worth changing the license mode of the server to per user from per device.

Comment: Added a response in an edit in the main post. I was surprised this didn't work for me though but I didn't bother persuing as it came back to the same issue. There is no way we can provide admin creds to non-admin staff.

Comment: I wonder if the browser is defaulting to the 64 Bit version, instead of the 32 Bit. Have you checked to see what version is launching?

Comment: Hadn't considered that, will check.